# Identifying Cast Iron Skillet - with weird pattern

Tags: cookware, cast-iron

My mother gave me an old skillet she had, and to me, it looked like a normal cast iron. I wanted to 'clean' it the way I normally clean and season my other pans, by scrubbing it with chain mail scrubber, then heating it up and oiling it. On the back of the skillet it just says "KOREA 8" SKILLET"

However when I got to scrubbing more layers came off than I anticipated and now it has me wondering if it is cast iron or something else? It has a weird pattern that was exposed that I have not seen before on other cast irons. The lighter rings in the spiral rust when exposed to water and let to air dry.

Anyone able to identify? Can I proceed with seasoning it in the oven with oil as regular?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I am not an expert on cast iron, but I believe this just means that it's a machine-milled piece, instead of one cast from a mold. There's nothing better or worse about it as far as I know as far as performance goes, I think it just means that it's a relatively newer piece, since pans made from casting tend to be older. Some people prefer the older ones.

Comment: Ah ok, good to know!

Comment: I've seen stuff that's been cast, then milled to give it a smoother surface .. so it's possible that it *is* cast, and may not be of recent manufacture.

Answer (score 4):

I have a Wagner pan from the 1990 that has the same pattern. They would cast and then mill the interior. Otherwise too rough like the outside of the pan.

Comment: Oh, and yes. I just seasoned mine and it came out great. In the oven on the cleaning cycle, then I had to grind it with the wire brush as it was very rusty, then oil and bake. Make sure you wipe off excess oil while it's hot as it can form a tacky coating.

Comment: I have one like it. It is MUCH nicer than raw cast. You can also occasionally find ones cast with a much finer sand, which I am told is similarly nice.

Answer (score 0):

It has been center milled smooth. With no other markings I here would think India To the Philippines made. Normally sold in the street stall area. As the bigger stores like a brand on them. There good pots & pans. Normally small foundries. Make them from scrap iron or other blends of scrap metal here.